# Facebook Like Not working for my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have generated facebook like code  for the site [Geoflake](http://geoflake.com) from this facebook url

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

When i click like in the "facebook test page", the count disappears.

Any one having same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a strict answer, I can agree that there is a problem. What is the 'facebook test page.'

When I click on the 'like' button on the URL provided the usual 'share' prompt appears and quickly disappears.  How did you generate the code?  And, I know this is usually kind of offensive, but did you read through all of the instructions?  From the end of that page

"When I click the Like button, the popup window (or "flyout") doesn't show. Why?

If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the overflow property set to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by setting setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden, such as visible, scroll, or auto."

Comment: Facebook test page. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ Enter geoflake.com in "Url to like" text box and click on like button, on the right side and your see the count disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the quotes around the href attribute:

```
<fb:like href=http://geoflake.com/DLZ4d0b7a8 send="true" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Try fixing that first.

(Also, it seems like your site is redirecting to the mobile site on Safari -- at least on my Mac. Perhaps you are testing for generic Webkit instead of mobile webkit?)

Comment: i will check on the safari. For Testing Enter geoflake.com in the text box "Url to Like" on the page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like  and then click on the like button on the right side. The button count dissapers ? don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I had two js scrips that are in my web page , one is with my app_id and another without app_id. I have removed one which doesn't have the app_id and it worked.